# Create order using REST API with multi-currency issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Using default order create rest API one issue was face, when order create using postman/curl than it will success and working fine but when same API hit using mobile app it causes issue like - base currency was USD and place order using another currency like -CAD,EUR order created and view in admin side only one currency was set or total will be same as base total with difference currency

Any have idea,help much appreciated.